# Why date difference start with zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

Implemented start date and end date to find the day difference. If i select start date today and end date today then difference is showing that 0 and i have disabled the weekends though its counting the weekends also. Here is my code.

```js
$("#startDate").datepicker({

  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
  changeMonth: true,
  todayHighlight: true,

  minDate: 0,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  todayHighlight: true,
  
  onSelect: function(dateStr) {
    var min = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Get selected date
    $("#endDate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', min || '0'); // Set other min, default to today
  }
});

$("#endDate").datepicker({

  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
  changeMonth: true,
  endDate: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
  minDate: 0,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  onSelect: function(dateStr) {

    var max = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Get selected date
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate');
    var start = $("#startDate").datepicker("getDate");
    var end = $("#endDate").datepicker("getDate");
    var days = (end - start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    $("#noofDays").val(days);

  }
});
```

Comment: If you check the console of your snippet you have an obvious error. You need to swap the order of your scripts so jQuery.js comes *before* Bootstrap, as it relies on jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used date difference calculation function in jquery. its working for me

```js
$("#startDate").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
  minDate: 0,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  maxDate: '+1Y+6M',
  onSelect: function(dateStr) {
    var min = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Get selected date
    $("#endDate").datepicker('option', 'minDate', min || '0'); // Set other min, default to today
  }
});

$("#endDate").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
  minDate: 0,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onSelect: function(dateStr) {
    var max = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Get selected date
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', max || '+1Y+6M'); // Set other max, default to +18 months
    var start = $("#startDate").datepicker("getDate");
    var end = $("#endDate").datepicker("getDate");
    var days = (end - start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    $("#noofDays").val(days);
  }
});
```